# Exception caught by printing

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a problem with trying to preview a PDF file. Whenever I try to display it, this error shows up:

```
════════ Exception caught by printing ══════════════════════════════════════════
The getter 'height' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: height
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here is my code for the PDF preview page. Sorry I know it's probably difficult to read, I'm new to flutter and mobile development!

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:helping_hand/models/campaign_model.dart';
import 'package:helping_hand/models/volunteer_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart' as pr;

class PrintCertificate extends StatefulWidget {
  final String campID;
  const PrintCertificate({Key? key, required this.campID}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PrintCertificate> createState() => _PrintCertificateState();
}

class _PrintCertificateState extends State<PrintCertificate> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  VolunteerModel loggedInUser = VolunteerModel();
  final volunteersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("volunteers");
  CampaignModel currentCamp = CampaignModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    volunteersRef.doc(user!.uid).get().then((value) {
      loggedInUser = VolunteerModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {
       
        volunteername = loggedInUser.volunteerName;
      });
    });
  }

  var camp;
  var camptitle;
  var volunteername;
  var imagge;
  var camporg;
  var campdate;
  var campdateseparated;
  var formatt;

  Future getCamp() async {
    camp = await volunteersRef
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .collection("campaigns")
        .doc(widget.campID)
        .get();
    camptitle = camp['title'];
    imagge = await pr.imageFromAssetBundle('assets/images/logo.png');
    camporg = camp['organizationName'];
  
    campdate = camp['datetime'];
    campdateseparated = DateTime.parse(campdate);
    formatt =
        "${campdateseparated.day}/${campdateseparated.month}/${campdateseparated.year}";
  }

  final pdf = pw.Document();

  Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, String title) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document(version: PdfVersion.pdf_1_5, compress: false);
    final font = await pr.PdfGoogleFonts.nunitoExtraLight();
    getCamp();
    while (camp == null) {
       await Future.delayed(
         const Duration(microseconds: 500));
      }
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: format,
        margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(20),
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Column(mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max, children: [
              pw.Image(imagge),
              pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
              pw.Row(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'Certificate of Achievement',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      // fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                      color: PdfColor.fromHex('#96c2ff'),
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'This Certificate is proudly presented to:',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    volunteername,
                    style: const pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(width: 20, height: 20),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'For participating in',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    camptitle,
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 27, color: PdfColor.fromHex("#6289bf")),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(width: 20, height: 20),
              pw.Row(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'Yours truly,',
                    style: const pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                  pw.Text(
                    camporg,
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25, color: PdfColor.fromHex("#b88a40"),
                        font: font),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                  pw.Text(
                    'Date of Participation:',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontStyle: pw.FontStyle.italic,
                      color: PdfColor.fromHex("#71858f"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Column(
                mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                  pw.Text(
                    formatt,
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontStyle: pw.FontStyle.italic,
                      // color: PdfColor.fromHex("#71858f")
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.white),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ];
        }));
    return pdf.save();
  }

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
   
        body: pr.PdfPreview(build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, camptitle))
       
        );
  }
}
```

and I made sure to have printing updated to its latest version. My Flutter version is 2.10.3. Here is an image reference for the error:

Error image

[image]

Comment: This error might be coming from different place , you can track by checking uses of `height` variable. also you can try providing default value in it or check null before using `height`

Comment: I looked elsewhere in the code for height, and I only used height for SizedBoxes and nothing else. I also checked for height on the previous page and all of the heights had a value. I think it might have to do with the pub dev printing package itself, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The issue might be here `_generatePdf` is a future method. you can wrap it with `FutureBuilder`.